# Difficulty in Arduino programming on LED

Tags: arduino

Im working on an arduino proramming where i have to one the led then off it then on the next one.. 16 LEDs all tgt and im using shift register MC74HC595AN aka 595 register. Im finding it really difficult to code them all by myself as I am still learning how to programme with Arduino. Anyone having the code or could work out on the code share it with me please? Any form of help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Here is the code that I did but doesnt seem to be working.

```
    const int button0Pin = 15;
    const int button1Pin = 1;
    const int button2Pin = 2;
    const int button3Pin = 3;
    const int button4Pin = 4;
    const int button5Pin = 5;
    const int button6Pin = 6;
    const int button7Pin = 7;



    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(button0Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button1Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button2Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button3Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button4Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button5Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button6Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button7Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(14, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);

    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:



    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(button0Pin, 1);
    digitalWrite(button1Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(button2Pin, 0);
    delay(5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just to be clear here, you are initializing pin 14 as something to receive input, however you never actually use it in your main loop to check if you are getting any input.

To make your life easier, consider naming the pins shorter names. Instead of "button0Pin" how about just "b0"?

Also, you may want to try using a for loop instead of what you are doing (writing out separate blocks of code, each with the output of 1 pin at a different spot)

You can read the arduino reference guides (I read it every time I'm programming) here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

and this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/arduino-uno-light-leds-right-to-left-and-then-reversed may be similar to the for loop you're needing.

Hope that helped, at least a little bit.

Comment: Never recommend renaming a variable to something that obfuscates its purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was just giving an example, since he writes it so many times. If he were to make a note in the beginning of the code saying "b#" refers to the number of the button pin, it shouldn't be a problem. In any case, since this specific program, however, has no other variables besides button pin variables, it should not matter how he choses to shorten the variable names "button#Pin".

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I see that you help in Python a lot. Do you mind checking out my question? I'm having trouble and it's really frustrating me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the pin modes properly, but then you do an awful lot of writing to `button2Pin`.

Also, if you don't actually have pin 14 connected to a supply then you should consider setting it to `INPUT_PULLUP` instead so that you don't consume excess power needlessly.